# why are my sprites not drawing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am learning how to make a minigame with javascript, but my player is not rendered.
I don´t know why. I am not getting any errors.

The startGame() starts with

How should I edit my code to get it to run and get the sprites to render?

Here's my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0"/>
</head>  
<body onload='startGame()'>

<script>

function startGame() {
    createCanvas.start();

}
let ninja = new Image();
let ninjaImage = "images/player/stand01.png"


const createCanvas = {
    canvas : document.createElement('canvas'),
    start() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 400;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}
function sprite(options){
    let that = {};
    that.context = options.context;
    that.width = options.width;
    that.height = options.height;
    that.image = options.image;
    return that;

    that.render = function () {
    that.context.drawImage(
    that.image, 0, 0, that.width, that.height, 0, 0, that.width, that.height);
    }
   player.render();
}

 player = sprite ({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    image: ninjaImage
});


</script>

</body>
<style>
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: grey;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a snippet, using the `<>` button, that includes both your JavaScript and your HTML. Make sure to make a [mcve].

Comment: You have unreachable code after `return that;` and you never use `ninja`. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Comment: ohh yeah, i returned something in the function, thank you for the tipp.

Comment: but, could you help me how i should change my code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have taken care of the early return, your code isn't working because you are likely because your render() function is being called when your player object is created. Before you can draw anything it's better to setup your canvas and context object first.

My recommendation for creating objects in a class like way is to use the function/prototype approach.

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  void function() {
   
   "use strict";
   
   /*
    In JS a 'class' is made up of two things
    
    A constructor function that attaches individual properties to every new instance
    (When a contructor is called with 'new' I.E. 'new Sprite()', the 'this' variable in the constructor
    is assigned to the newly created object.
    
    The other part is a prototype that holds shared properties between instances of
    the 'class'. (in an instance prototype values are accessible via the this keyword).
   */
   
   // Constructor function
   function Sprite(x,y,width,height,image) {
    this.x = x || 0.0;
    this.y = y || 0.0;
    this.width = width || 1.0;
    this.height = height || 1.0;
    this.image = image || null;
   }
   
   // Prototype object (Shared between instances)
   Sprite.prototype = {
    render: function(ctx) {
     if (this.image) {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image,this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
     } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
     }
    }
   };
   
   var canvasWidth = 180;
   var canvasHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var sprite = null;
   
   var image = new Image();
    image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnNgY.png";
   
   // window.onload, called when page has loaded
   onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    
    sprite = new Sprite(65,55,50,50,image);
    sprite.render(ctx);
   }
   
  }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```